# Standing wave and energy conservation

Tags: energy, waves, energy-conservation, acoustics, superposition

Consider a one-dimensional standing wave formed on the interval $0 \leq x \leq L$.

Let's say that this is an ideal model motivated by a string as a medium with both ends closed.

Assume that there is **no energy loss** in the process of either transfer or reflection of the waves.

Also say that, though it may be impossible practically, that the standing wave is formed by some initial consecutive pulses given to the same direction (say, to the right so that we can model it as something like $A\sin(kx-wt)$).

Now, my question. In this ideal case the **conservation of energy** should hold, and we can deduce that the pulses will be reflected and keep moving to the right and left without damping, so once the standing wave is formed (at time $t=t_1$) then for the rest of the time ($t \in [t_1, \infty)$) the standing wave should be kept without being destroyed. Is it right?

And also if you find any primary misunderstanding of concepts from my question please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, in the ideal world this wave will continue to exist forever. This is not special to standing waves, but I suppose that it is something in the formulation/shape of the standing wave that makes you doubt validity of the energy conservation?

Comment: Something special about standing wave is that it’ll retain shape. Others will have a dispersion.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish Dispersion is a property of a wave packet, and not for every type of waves (e.g., the electromagnetic waves in vacuum are dispersionless). Also, dispersion is not dissipation.

Comment: Dispersion is a property of the medium. And with my above comment I meant due to dispersion, arbitrary shape will not be retained.

Comment: A plane wave will not be affected by dispersion. Also, I do not see how it is relevant to  the OP's doubts about the energy conservation.

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to note the difference between standing wave and pulses since OP is sending pulses.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish Good point.

Comment: Hmm ok I see how the obvious fact that the energy conservation holds in the standing wave is indeed true. I want to talk more about the initial pulse. It feels like I shouldn't be giving discrete pulses in order to create the standing wave, because there should exist the progressive wave that superposes with the one reflected at the boundary. I am very confused about the initial mechanism from the creation of continuous pulses (progressive waves) up to the eventual formation of a standing wave. If I understand this then I would be able to think about how the standing wave is kept over time.

Comment: And also about the boundary conditions - thinking about them I feel like there should be something special about the formation of a standing wave in such a situation. Sorry I'm really confused. If you've got any recommendation for me to read to understand concepts properly please go ahead. Thanks.

Comment: @curious Indeed, it was not clear to me that what mostly interests you is how the standing wave is formed. Perhaps, you could ask it as a new question? Again, it is not specific to a standing wave, one faces similar issues when discussing formation of a plane wave - it is probably more discussed.

Comment: It was just another question independent from the original question. But yes, I think the original question can be reduced to the discussion of formation of waves and the principle of superposition. So I created another post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576609/195374